# Why aren't custom JavaScript files loading in Firefox, when other JavaScript files in the same directory are?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a very weird problem in Firefox ( version 3.5.2), and I am using Firebug ( version 1.4.2). **Google Chrome doesn't have this problem**.

A custom script ( `bpoCases.js`) I wrote, which is put inside the same directory as other javascript files such as `jquery.js`, is not loading, whereas `jquery.js` is loading. And when I check the HTML, it seems to load the problematic javascript alright:

[http://lh4.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SqHJZeihjqI/AAAAAAAAFHg/1gNhmt8h6oY/s800/htmlthing.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/hz8MhCpBfGyA7uURsaSlqQ?feat=embedwebsite)

However when I tried to invoke the function in `bpoCases.js`, nothing happened. A look inside the script panel in firebug indicates that the `bpoCases.js` is unavailable for the purpose of viewing source and debugging ( note that I *can'*t go to `bpoCases.js` and step through the source code, the only js files that are available are `jquery.js` and `json.js`).

[http://lh4.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SqHLMhUkbRI/AAAAAAAAFHo/UuLEszkE3zw/s800/missingbpoCases.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/4CwH641kU96wyuVDZH2yrA?feat=embedwebsite)

The browser was working fine yesterday, but it went crazy this morning. And I didn't do anything to it.

**Clarification: I `did` place my JavaScript logic inside a different js file, and placed a calling to that js file from my HTML. The reason why you see a conflation of `script` tag and the js source file is because firebug displays it that way, not because I write the code that way ( as If I don't know anything about best practices)**

**Anyway I have accepted a solution... thanks!**

Comment: Try clearing your cache?  Also, make sure the files are being retrieved properly using the Net tab.

Comment: @kangax, For convenience, Firebug automatically inlines scripts like that once they are loaded.

Comment: Why is there both - content in a SCRIPT tag *and* "src" attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a syntax error in the script which causes it to not show up in the Scripts tab.

Enable the Console tab and it will show you any syntax errors encountered.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution I need-- there is a syntax error at this line: var idSelect=$"#priorityStatus"+parseData.id;

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are using the  tag to both load the bpoCases.js file and to contain locally written JavaScript.

Place the call to the bpoCases.js file in it's own separate  tag. Then start a new  tag block for your locally written code.

Comment: That's the result from the firebug console-- as a matter of face I really did place a call to the bpoCases.js in my html, and start of my code inside that js file.